# HTML Forms answer to a log file

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hi community I want my HTML Forms answers to a log file. 
How do I do that? 
I haven't tried anything yet 
Can you please help me 
If I am asking in a rude way I am very sorry and Thank you

Comment: You've a server-side task at hands, but not a word about your server in the question ..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just by using HTML you can't achieve this, as HTML is a client side technology (i.e it runs on client browser) you need to use a server side technology like PHP/NodeJS/Java to write the data to a log file on your hosting server.

To achieve this with PHP follow the below link  
[https://www.codespeedy.com/save-html-form-data-in-a-txt-text-file-in-php/#:~:text=Create%20a%20PHP%20file%20and%20put%20the%20below%20code%20and%20save%20it.&text=%3F%3E-,%3C!,%3E%20%3C%3F](https://www.codespeedy.com/save-html-form-data-in-a-txt-text-file-in-php/#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20PHP%20file%20and%20put%20the%20below%20code%20and%20save%20it.&text=%3F%3E-,%3C!,%3E%20%3C%3F)

To achieve this with NodeJS try using the below link 
https://nodejs.dev/learn/writing-files-with-nodejs

Comment: Please put the code as text instead of links.